# Как сделать пошаговую прокрутку колесиком мыши?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть такая конструкция. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно сделать в блоке `.sidebar_news_block` плавную пошаговую прокрутку колесиком мыши, по блокам `.sidebar_news__item`? Возможно ли?

```css
.sidebar_news_block {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.sidebar_news {
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.sidebar_news__item {
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: justify;
}
```

```html
<div class="sidebar_news_block">
  <h2>Красивый заголовок</h2>
  <div class="sidebar_news">
    <div class="sidebar_news__item">
      Белая береза Под моим окном Принакрылась снегом, Точно серебром.
    </div>
    <div class="sidebar_news__item">
      Ах, метель такая, просто черт возьми! Забивает крышу белыми гвоздьми. Только мне не страшно, и в моей судьбе Непутевым сердцем я прибит к тебе.
    </div>
    <div class="sidebar_news__item">
      Вот уж вечер. Роса Блестит на крапиве. Я стою у дороги, Прислонившись к иве.
    </div>
    <div class="sidebar_news__item">
      Хорошо и тепло, Как зимой у печки. И березы стоят, Как большие свечки. И вдали за рекой, Видно, за опушкой, Сонный сторож стучит Мертвой колотушкой.
    </div>
    <div class="sidebar_news__item">
      Задремали звезды золотые, Задрожало зеркало затона
    </div>
    <div class="sidebar_news__item">
      Улыбнулись сонные березки, Растрепали шелковые косы. Шелестят зеленые сережки, И горят серебряные росы.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Что Вы понимаете, под `плавной пошаговой прокруткой колесиком мыши, по блокам`?  Чтобы в `sidebar_news_block` при скроле отображался только 1 блок? Что тогда делать, если остается много пустого места?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вроде как все работает.
П.С.: как сделать, чтобы код можно было выполнить на сайте?

```js
 var sidebarNewsBlock = document.getElementById("sidebarNewsBlock"),
    children = sidebarNewsBlock.children,
    allChildren =[],
    stepScroll = 20,//регулировка скорости прокрутки №1
    nodeElem;

//получаем всех детей sidebarNewsBlock
 for (var i=0; i<children.length; i++){
  if (children[i].children.length > 0) {
   for (var h=0; h<children[i].children.length; h++){
    allChildren.push(children[i].children[h]);
   }
  } else if(children[i].children.length == 0){
   allChildren.push(children[i]);
  }
}

sidebarNewsBlock.onwheel = function(event){
 window.event.returnValue = false;
 var r = event.deltaY;
 //определяем направление движения колесика мышки
  if (r>0){
   for (var i=0; i<allChildren.length; i++){
   var t = allChildren[i].getBoundingClientRect();
    if (t.top >0) {
     nodeElem = allChildren[i]
     lowScroll();
     break;
     }
   }
 } else if (r<0) {
  for (var i=0; i<allChildren.length; i++){
   var t = allChildren[i].getBoundingClientRect();
   if ((t.top <= 0 && t.top > -2) || t.top > 0){
    var g = i-1;
    if (g>=0) {
     nodeElem = allChildren[g];
     lowScroll();
     break;
     }else if (g<0){
      sidebarNewsBlock.scrollTo(0,0)
      break;    
     }
    }
   }
 }
}

function lowScroll(){
 var k = nodeElem.getBoundingClientRect();
 var t = sidebarNewsBlock.scrollTop+sidebarNewsBlock.clientHeight;
    var timer = 0;
 if (k.top >0){
  if (t == sidebarNewsBlock.scrollHeight) {return};//определяем достигла ли прокрутка низа
  if (stepScroll < k.top){
   sidebarNewsBlock.scrollBy(0,stepScroll);
   timer = setTimeout(lowScroll, 50);//регулировка скорости прокрутки №2
  } else if (stepScroll > k.top) {
   sidebarNewsBlock.scrollBy(0,k.top+1);
            if (timer == 0) return;
   clearTimeout(timer);
   
  }

 } else if (k.top < 0) {
  var reverseStepScroll = 0-stepScroll;
  if (reverseStepScroll > k.top){
   sidebarNewsBlock.scrollBy(0,reverseStepScroll);
   timer = setTimeout(lowScroll, 50);//регулировка скорости прокрутки №2
  } else if (stepScroll >= k.top) {
   sidebarNewsBlock.scrollBy(0,k.top+1);
   clearTimeout(timer);
  }
 }
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
}

.sidebar_news_block {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.sidebar_news {
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.sidebar_news__item {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: justify;
}
```

```html
 

   <div id="sidebarNewsBlock" class="sidebar_news_block">
<h2>  Красивый заголовок</h2>
<div class="sidebar_news">
<div class="sidebar_news__item">
 1.Белая береза Под моим окном Принакрылась снегом, Точно серебром.
</div>
<div class="sidebar_news__item">
2.Ах, метель такая, просто черт возьми! Забивает крышу белыми гвоздьми. Только мне не страшно, и в моей судьбе Непутевым сердцем я прибит к тебе.Ах, метель такая, просто черт возьми! Забивает крышу белыми гвоздьми. Только мне не страшно, и в моей судьбе Непутевым сердцем я прибит к тебе.Ах, метель такая, просто черт возьми! Забивает крышу белыми гвоздьми. Только мне не страшно, и в моей судьбе Непутевым сердцем я прибит к тебе.Ах, метель такая, просто черт возьми! Забивает крышу белыми гвоздьми. Только мне не страшно, и в моей судьбе Непутевым сердцем я прибит к тебе.Ах, метель такая, просто черт возьми! Забивает крышу белыми гвоздьми. Только мне не страшно, и в моей судьбе Непутевым сердцем я прибит к тебе.
</div>
<div class="sidebar_news__item">
3.Вот уж вечер.  Роса Блестит на крапиве. Я стою у дороги, Прислонившись к иве.Вот уж вечер.  Роса Блестит на крапиве. Я стою у дороги, Прислонившись к иве.Вот уж вечер.  Роса Блестит на крапиве. Я стою у дороги, Прислонившись к иве.Вот уж вечер.  Роса Блестит на крапиве. Я стою у дороги, Прислонившись к иве.Вот уж вечер.  Роса Блестит на крапиве. Я стою у дороги, Прислонившись к иве.Вот уж вечер.  Роса Блестит на крапиве. Я стою у дороги, Прислонившись к иве.Вот уж вечер.  Роса Блестит на крапиве. Я стою у дороги, Прислонившись к иве.Вот уж вечер.  Роса Блестит на крапиве. Я стою у дороги, Прислонившись к иве.Вот уж вечер.  Роса Блестит на крапиве. Я стою у дороги, Прислонившись к иве.Вот уж вечер.  Роса Блестит на крапиве. Я стою у дороги, Прислонившись к иве.Вот уж вечер.  Роса Блестит на крапиве. Я стою у дороги, Прислонившись к иве.
</div>
<div class="sidebar_news__item">
4.Хорошо и тепло, Как зимой у печки. И березы стоят, Как большие свечки. И вдали за рекой, Видно, за опушкой, Сонный сторож стучит Мертвой колотушкой.
</div>
<div class="sidebar_news__item">
5.Задремали звезды золотые, Задрожало зеркало затона
</div>
<div class="sidebar_news__item">
6.Улыбнулись сонные березки, Растрепали шелковые косы. Шелестят зеленые сережки, И горят серебряные росы.
</div>
<div class="sidebar_news__item">
7.Улыбнулись сонные березки, Растрепали шелковые косы. Шелестят зеленые сережки, И горят серебряные росы.
</div>
<div class="sidebar_news__item">
8.Улыбнулись сонные березки, Растрепали шелковые косы. Шелестят зеленые сережки, И горят серебряные росы.
</div>
<div class="sidebar_news__item">
9.Улыбнулись сонные березки, Растрепали шелковые косы. Шелестят зеленые сережки, И горят серебряные росы.
</div>
<div class="sidebar_news__item">
10.Улыбнулись сонные березки, Растрепали шелковые косы. Шелестят зеленые сережки, И горят серебряные росы.
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Внес правки в код

Comment: Все - написал еще оду проверку. Ошибка больше не появляется

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял вашу задачу. То вам подойдет [fullPage.js](https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/)

Comment: Ну если для решения вашей задачи необходим целый плагин, то излишним он не будет. Вы можете конечно, написать свой собственный плагин. Я лишь предложил путь наименьшего сопротивления.